# What is "rail pack" type of packing for electronic components?

Tags: triac

I found triac from WeEn Semiconductors next type: BTA412Y-600B.
There is a link to official page of this component:

http://www.ween-semi.com/pip.aspx?p=BTA412Y-600B

For this product defined next type of packing:

> Horizontal, Rail Pack

I suppose that is tube form of packing. But am not sure.

Can anybody clarify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the BTA412 comes in a TO-220 housing (which is used a lot), I expect them to be shipped in a tube like this:

[image]

It would surprise me if anything different was used since this is the standard way to package components in a TO-220 housing.

Comment: Removing the top surface in the size of one component allows them to be taken out easily and still stored safely.

Comment: +1 Never heard them called that though. Just "tubes". Hated that packaging every time I picked one up and forgot to put the rubber bung in the end....

Comment: Good tip that solves my problem above @SolarMike

Comment: @SolarMike I don't understand. Can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: use the plastic container that they come in as "accessible storage" by making an opening at one end that allows you to remove one at a time without them all falling out... Think about how some storage shelves in supermarkets are angled so the "next" one slides to the bottom to be easily accessible...